# Trying to create a generic mapper in mapstruct for all the fields with target and source as String

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have this requirement in which for all the String -> String mappings, I need to check if the source string is empty and if it is I want to return null. I thought this would work but unfortunately doesn't

```
@Mapping(source = "in", target = ".", qualifiedByName = "stringConverter")
abstract String mapString(String in);
```

I thought this would generate a function like

```
String mapString(String in) {
    if ( in == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    String string = stringConverter(in);

    return string;
}
```

Or something similar. Here stringConverter just basically checks if the string is empty and returns null if so, else the original string. But in turn what I actually get is

```
String mapString(String in) {
    if ( in == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    String string = new String();

    return string;
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic function that handles mappings for all the string fields when using mapstruct?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Have you considered opening an [issue in their github repository](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct)? I had good experience reporting bugs to the mapstruct-developers in the past.

Comment: I think for your purpose is something like StringUtils from commons.lang a better opinion. Mapstruct map from classA to classB and not from classA to classA.

Comment: @Tr1monster Don't really want to do that as that would mean defining a `@Mapping` with an `expression` individually for all the fields in all the mapped objects which have string fields even for those with same field names(both source and target)

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct is meant for mapping beans and not for mapping between Strings.

You need to write a custom method for mapping between `String` and MapStruct will use that method.

```
public class StringConverter {

    public static String map(String value) {
        return (value == null || value.isEmpty()) ? null : value;
    }

}
```